# Show that g(n) is O(g(n))

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I don't get how to show it---I take the log of both sides, and?
This question is to prove that `f(n)` is `O(g(n))`, which I know how to do for things that have the same base. not as much for this.
`2^(sqrt(log(n))` is `O(n(^4/3))`

Comment: Maybe better researched on https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sufficiently large `n`, `sqrt(log(n))` is positive and bounded from above by `log(n)`. Since `2^x` is monotonically increasing, `2^sqrt(log(n))` is bounded from above by `2^log(n) = n`. Moreover, for large `n`, `n` is clearly bounded from above by `n^(4/3)`. Therefore the original function itself is bounded from above by `n^(4/3)` as well.